# How to use the command "Jar x "?

Tags: java, cmd

I've just started studying Java.

I know I can extract a jar file with command `jar xf jarname.jar`

But I'm confused about this [command `jar x` and useless new lines][jar x and new lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttv8e.png)

1. Enter  `jar x`，press the *Enter* key.
2. Enter `TicTacToe.jar`(what i want to extract sth from),press the Enter key.
3. Nothing else happened expect  generating a new line.

Please tell me why

Can't 'x' be used by itself?

Or

I should use some special command in cmd？

Comment: @PinkBuster A hint for the future: It is never a waste of time to read the documentation of a program, best before first time using it. In this case I recommend to read the [jar documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/jar.html). `jar xf jarname.jar` is in real `jar --extract --file jarname.jar` or `jar -x -f jarname.jar` or `jar -xf jarname.jar`. `jar xf jarname.jar` is in real the worst syntax, but a user has to enter one character fewer than better `jar -xf jarname.jar`.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks a lot ! I think I know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no `f` option is given to specify an archive file, data (not its name) is read from standard input like in:

- `cat file.jar | jar x`;
- `type file.jar | jar x` (Windows); or
- `jar x < file.jar`

Same true when creating a JAR file, without `f` option, data is written to standard output.

Comment: Thank so much ，it‘s works ! could  you explain why 'jar x' will  generate new lines ,please?

Comment: @PinkBuster: it doesn't. The newlines are *your input*. Note that this usage of `jar` is rather rare. Or put differently: I suspect it's **mostly** done by accident and rarely on purpose.